# Can't browse all the table

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework-5, sql-server-2012-express

I have problem with the Entity Framework ver. 5 `ConnectionString` with ADO.NET Entity Data Model. When I use the generated `connectionString` with *Username* and *Password* I can't map/browse all the table from my database.

```
<connectionStrings><add name="myEntities" 
                        connectionString="metadata=res://*/myDbase.csdl
                        |res://*/myDbase.ssdl|res://*/myDbase.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
                        provider connection string=&quot;data source=PCName\SQLEXPRESS;
                        initial catalog=myDbase;user id=myusername;password=2143;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
                        providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I need to use *Username* and *Password* for the requirements of the server so I can connect my project to the server using the Entity Framework ver. 5. What would be the solution for my problem? Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I re-configure the Server `log-on as NetworkService` and re-construct the `connectionString` my problem is solved.

```
<connectionStrings><add name="myEntities" 
                        connectionString="metadata=res://*/myDbase.csdl
                        |res://*/myDbase.ssdl|res://*/myDbase.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
                        provider connection string=&quot;data source=PCName\SQLEXPRESS;
                        initial catalog=myDbase;user id=myusername;password=2143;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;integrated security=true;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
                        providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Reference: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/08/15/a-troubleshooting-guide-for-entity-framework-connections-amp-migrations.aspx